# Sufficient condition for a sequence of indepent events

Tags: probability

Suppose $0 \leq p_n \leq 1$ and put $\alpha_n = \min(p_n, 1-p_n)$. Show that, if $\sum_n \alpha_n$ converges, then on some discrete probability space there exist independent events $A_n$ satisfying $P(A_n) = p_n$.

Hint Enough

Comment: +1 Here is a tiny hint: I was puzzling over why the convergence assumption is needed, since it seems one could easily construct a space with such events $A_n$ (think of an infinite sequence of coin flips, where the $p_n$ are the chances of heads at flip $n$) and realized that the difficulty lies in constructing a *discrete* space.

Comment: @whuber: May be some countable subset will help.

Comment: I would instead suggest pondering what the convergence assumption provides you and how you can use that to find a discrete distribution, perhaps by means of a limiting operation.